# Make one cell's value dependent on another's in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps

I am trying to setup a doc to keep track of my AWS instances. How would I go about setting up a script so that my "Cost" cell would be dependent on the Instance Type. For example, if I am adding a new instance, and I add "t2.micro" in the "Instance type" column the "Cost" cell would automatically populate with a set value. Any help or direction to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't use the Excel tag for Google sheets questions

Answer (score 0):

One path is to use the [LOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) function.

With instance and cost being columns A and B, you'd make a list elsewhere of your options (t2.micro/$200). In [the linked example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZOvHcBi-FWJ8JDa7-Q-Jg1WU_koC1DdFeFTLn3dFovM/edit#gid=0) I did it on the same page in columns G/H (but you could put it on another page or elsewhere).

I then set `Data>Validation>List from a Range` for Column A to be the values in column G. That give me a nice drop down of the instance types.

In Column B, I set the function `=LOOKUP(A1,$G$1:$H$4)` and drag it down. It references the value in cell A1 (instance) and then compares it to your list to pull the cost.